# Unique linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume the following:
$v_1 = -u_1 + 2u_2 + 0u_3$
And
$v_2 = 3u_1 - u_2 + 0u_3$

The expressions of $v_1$ and $v_2$ as linear combinations of $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$ are not unique. What is the meaning of 'not unique' here and what is an example of when it would be unique?

Comment: $(1,2) = 1(1,0)+2(0,1) +0(1,1)$ vs $(1,2)=0(1,0)+1(0,1)+1(1,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expressions of $v_1 $ and $v_2 $ is not unique.

for example $ v_1 = -u_1 +2u_2 + 0u_1 +0u_3 $ and $v_2 = 3u_1-u_2+0u_1 +0u_3$

The expressions would be unique , for example, when $u_1, u_2 , u_3 $ perform a basis for some vector space

Comment: Thank you for the answer...maybe the issue here is that I am not aware of what a basis is yet?

Comment: Do you what is linearly independent set of vectors? @TsTeaTime

Comment: You haven't used $u_3$, Liad – I think you're missing the point of the example.

Comment: I could  add $+0 u_3 $

Comment: is this is what you mean ? @GerryMyerson

Comment: I know of linear independence but won't claim to understand it fully at this point.

Comment: So if the vectors are linearly independent than the representation of each vector in their span is unique (do you what span is ? ) @TsTeaTime

Comment: I am covering span now and that is where this problem is coming from. The next chapters are linear independence and I see basis ahead as well

Comment: if the vectors is not linear independent so at least one of them belongs to the span of the other vectors (That's a theorem that you would probably see) so you can write this vector as a linear combination of the others, so it doesn't have a unique expression.

Comment: Not sure I understand yet, but I really appreciate the help.. I think I need to read the linear independence more carefully and come back to this.

Comment: Ok, if you have any questions you can ask me i could try to help

Comment: Awesome...thanks a ton @Liad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43194/discussion-between-liad-and-tsteatime).

Answer (score 1):

I think the comment from @Bye_World is closer to the mark here, so I'll expand on it.

Suppose $v_1=(1,2)$, $u_1=(-1,0)$, $u_2=(0,1)$, and $u_3=(1,1)$. Then $$v_1=-u_1+2u_2+0u_3$$ but also $$v_1=0u_1+u_2+u_3$$ so the expression of $v_1$ as a linear combination of $u_1,u_2,u_3$ is not unique.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $0u_2$ and $u_3$ in the first equation? Are you saying that $v_1$ can be represented by many forms of $u$ and that is the meaning of unique here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the first equation is correct as it stands. Why do you think it's wrong? Another option is $v_1=u_1+0u_2+2u_3$. In fact, there are infinitely many expressions for $v_1$ as a linear combination of $u_1$, $u_2$, and $u_3$.  If there were only one, then we'd say $v_1$ has a unique representation. But since there's more than one, we say $v_1$ doesn't have a unique representation as a linear combination of $u_1$, $u_2$, and $u_3$.

Comment: Ahh! I understand...sorry for my confusion.